# sql error ora-00933 sql command not properly ended delete

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I try to delete some data from three tables, using JOIN. But I have this error :

```
 SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
    00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

This is my query:

```
DELETE FROM News JOIN News_Author
ON News_Author.news_id=News.news_id JOIN Author 
ON News_Author.author_id=Author.author_id  WHERE news_id=16;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This query looks way too complicated. Why not a plain `DELETE FROM News WHERE news_id = 16` ?

Comment: yes, I decide that  better delete data in three queries.

Comment: `delete` doesn't have a `join` part, please read the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8005.htm#SQLRF01505

Answer (score 0):

can you try this..

```
DELETE News FROM News NS JOIN News_Author NA
ON NA.news_id=NS.news_id JOIN Author Ar
ON NA.author_id=Ar.author_id  WHERE news_id=16;
```

Comment: I think it will be better, if I delete in three queries. without JOIN)

Comment: `delete` doesn't have a `join` part.